# Auto generate function in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table named 'Customer'.

This table contains a unique Identification field for each customer named 'CustomerNo'.
It should be in the format : First an alphabet Starting from A-Z.

Then a four digit number starting from 1-9999 and the next is a three digit number starting from 1-999.This is a unique field.So it shoudn't repeat in the table Customer.

E.g:   A1000-100.

Is there any function to generate this format?

```
Table structure
-----------------------
CustomerID         CustomerName          CustomerNo

1                 John                   A1000-100
2                 Sajan                  A1001-100
```

Comment: is your example correct or should it be 2 Sajan A1000-101?

Comment: Example can't be correct as the first number for Sajan is > 9999.

Comment: i have corrected my eaxample.

Comment: Given the ranges of number described above - would the first customer number not be A0001-001?

Comment: no problem.the range is 1-9999.

Comment: So what is the order of the increments? It seems like you are saying that the middle number 1-9999 increments but then does the A increment or the -100? It seems unnatural that the middle number increments before the right most number.

Comment: the right most number increments first till 999,then middle number till 9999.After that combination finishes it starts from the next albhabet.here it is B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a normal auto incrementing identity column and the following formula (possibly in a derived column) to map this to display format.

```
CHAR((id-1)/9999/999 + 65) + 
RIGHT('0000' + CAST(1 + (id-1)%(999*9999)/999 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) + 
'-' + 
RIGHT('000' + CAST(1 + (id-1)%999 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
```

This avoids the need for you to have to deal with any concurrency issues yourself.

Comment: My format starts from this :A0001-001.In the above query there is no alphabet.i am not using any id

Comment: @Adu - I propose you add an id column and let SQL Server take care of auto incrementing it. This avoids you having to deal with concurrency issues yourself in the allocation of these ids. The alphabet character is added by the `CHAR` function. e.g. try `declare @id int set @id = 1 select CHAR((@id-1)/9999/999 + 65) + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(1 + (@id-1)%(999*9999)/999 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) + '-' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(1 + (@id-1)%999 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)`